# Como saber qual script está sendo executado em determinado elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, firebug

No Firebug é possível saber qual CSS está sendo aplicado no elemento HTML, porém não é possível saber qual JavaScript está sendo executado no elemento HTML, tem como saber isso?

Comment: Como assim javascript sendo executado no elemento html?

Comment: tipo, as vezes executamos funções javascript em elementos html, como por exemplo document.getElementByiD("nomeDoElemento"); eu quer saber como eu faço pra descobrir que esse javascript está sendo executado.

Comment: @user8465 Neste exemplo não há nenhum javascript sendo executado sobre o elemento. O elemento está apenas sendo selecionado.

Comment: mas foi só pra exemplificar pow

Comment: @user8465 O que estou dizendo é que não é um exemplo útil. Continuamos sem saber o que você quer.

Comment: no firebug quando você clicka em um elemento html ele mostra ao lado o css que está sendo aplicado, o que eu quero é quando você click no elemento html seja mostrado o javascript que está sendo aplicado, entendeu ?

Comment: Você pode por breakpoints no Javascript para capturar o momento em que ele é executado, mas desconheço recurso que faça o que você deseja.

Comment: @user8465 Atualize a pergunta com um "código javascript sendo aplicado sobre um elemento", daí podemos saber se há uma maneira de achar esse código sem conhecê-lo previamente.

Comment: Não existe JavaScript sendo executado "no" elemento. O JavaScript, como o @Beterraba já falou, apenas SELECIONA o elemento e, às vezes, escuta eventos disparados pelo elemento. Você pode ver os "Event Listeners" do elemento no Firebug, mas outros tipos de interações não são exibidas porque não fazem sentido.

Comment: nesse exemplo só seleciona, mas por exemplo se você faz um relógio dinâmico que muda a cada segundo em javascript e esse relógio é mostrado dentro de uma div, isso quer dizer que dentro dessa div tem um javascript sendo executado =)

Comment: @user8465 O JavaScript não é executado "dentro da div", ele é executado globalmente para toda a página - podendo ou não alterar o conteúdo da div. Como você pode guardar uma referência pra div em qualquer variável (ou mesmo nenhuma variável - se você fizer a seleção e a alteração na hora) fica impossível saber todo trecho de código que toca numa div, e portanto em que parte da página (inline ou script externo) aquele código foi definido. A maneira mais garantida é **lendo** o código-fonte mesmo... :P

Comment: Oi, @user8465, dá um confere em [O que é console.log?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/201)

Answer (score 3):

Podes apurar quais os eventos anexados a determinado objeto do DOM via Firebug a partir da versão 1.12, onde foi introduzida a função [`getEventListeners(target)`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/GetEventListeners) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

1. Abres o Firebug por exemplo com a tecla <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Clicas sobre o separador `console`;
3. Digitas na linha de comandos a função passando como parâmetro um objeto de DOM.

   Exemplo para recolher eventos anexados à tag `<body/>`:

   ```
   getEventListeners(document.body);
   ```

   O resultado será algo do tipo:

   [image: Imagem ilustrativa]

**Notas:**

Não parece funcionar com objetos de jQuery, deverás fazer uso de objetos DOM "normais".

Deverás esperar que a página esteja totalmente carregada para garantir que o DOM foi todo lido e está pronto a ser pesquisado pela `getEventListeners()`.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando jQuery, existe um plugin para o firefox que permite que você saiba que função está atachada para um elemento html. O nome do plugin é [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/firequery/).

Comment: Foi mal, acho que nossas edições colidiram. É legal esperar 5 minutos depois que alguém faz uma edição. Esse é o tempo que dá para corrigir coisas sem gerar um item no histórico (*grace period*). Tinha colocado o resumo do plugin pois é boa prática colocar um resumo do que o leitor vai encontrar no link oferecido. Tudo de bom!