# O que é console.log?

Tags: javascript

Vejo isso em alguns arquivos JavaScript:

```
console.log(algumaCoisa);
console.log("alguma coisa");
```

Para que serve e como funciona?

Estou tentando fazer um `log()` personalizado para um Userscript (vide [How can I log information without using alert in userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10120761/1287812)) e me dei conta que não conheço o que está por trás do `console.log`.

Comment: Some tips:

You can use colors to have a better view of:
console.log('%c Sample Text', 'color:green;');

Or add some VAR in the text using:
console.log(\`Sample ${variable}\`, 'color:green;');

When you have some OBJECTS, you can show using table:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_table.asp

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Objeto Console

O `console` é efetivamente um objeto com diversos métodos associados.

O objeto `console` fornece acesso à consola de depuração do navegador. O funcionamento deste objeto varia de navegador para navegador mas existem determinados métodos que são vistos como um standard. Um desses métodos é o `log()`.

## Método log

O método `log()` existe essencialmente para permitir o envio de dados para a consola de depuração do navegador. Pode ser enviada qualquer informação, normalmente com o intuito de depurar código.

**Exemplo da consola do Firefox:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Primir <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> para chamar a mesma no Firefox.

## Considerações

Como este objeto varia e não existe ainda um standard a reger o funcionamento e metodologia do mesmo, existem algumas considerações a ter:

```js
// Exemplo a enviar algo para a consola do navegador
var s = "bubu";
console.log(s);
```

#### Potenciais problemas:

- O utilizador pode ter desligado a consola;
- O navegador pode não ter consola Web;
- O método que estamos a utilizar pode não funcionar em determinado navegador.

Em JavaScript, uma falha de execução pode resultar num bloqueio de todo o restante JavaScript. Se por exemplo fizermos uso do `console.log(X)` quando a consola não existe ou o método `log()` não existe, vamos ter um erro no nosso código.

#### Alternativa:

Podemos fazer uso de um [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) para tentar enviar para a consola e em caso de falha agir de outra forma:

```js
function consola(s) {
    try { console.log(s); } catch (e) { alert(s); }
}
```

E assim se correr bem, a informação estará na consola, se correr mal vai ser emitido um `alert()` com a informação que iria para a consola.

Claro que podemos não fazer nada ou enviar uma chamada de Ajax para um servidor com o erro se o mesmo for critico e tiver que ser registado "doa a quem doer".

```js
/* Enviar algo para a consola do navegador com fallback 
 * fazendo uso da função já declarada conforme visto em cima
 */
var s = "bubu";
consola(s);
```

---

## Consolas

Como explicado, não existe propriamente um standard para a consola web, pelo que ficam algumas referências às páginas de ajuda de cada um:

- [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)
- [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.51/en/devtools.html)

---

<sup>Nota: Resposta a evoluir dentro de alguns dias logo que termine de compilar mais informação relevante sobre este assunto.</sup>

Comment: Yes! `StackExchange.resposta.carimbar('Canônica')`

Answer (score 51):

Isso escreve uma mensagem qualquer no LOG do browser, que pode ser visualizada a qualquer momento.

Essas mensagens podem ser usadas com vários propósitos:

- auxiliar na programação (tipo quando você dá um `alert` só para ver se um método foi chamado... funciona da mesma forma, mas sem interromper o fluxo)
- instruções de uso de uma biblioteca... imagine que uma função se tornou obsoleta, e você quer que as pessoas parem de usar a função, mas sem lançar uma exceção... se bem que neste caso, outras funções podem ser usadas: `console.warn` seria mais recomendável.

Outros métodos de LOG existentes:

- `console.info`
- `console.warn`
- `console.error`
- `console.debug`

Todas elas servem para escrever mensagens, a diferença, entre os métodos está justamente no significado da mensagem. Veja como ficam as mensagens com cada um desses métodos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>(exemplo: janela de console do chrome)</sup>

Comment: +1 por mostrar os outros métodos do objeto console

Comment: Eu não sabia dos outros métodos além do 'log'. Excelente resposta! +1

Answer (score 26):

`console.log` é um método entre vários outros disponíveis para o [console de debug dos navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console).

[Lista de outros métodos do console.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console#M%C3%A9todos)

`console.log` é utilizado para a emissão de informações de registro em geral. Por exemplo:

```
var algumObjeto = {
  str: "Algum texto",
  id: 5
};
console.log(algumObjeto);
```

Saída:

```
({str:"Algum texto", id:5})
```

```js
var algumObjeto = {
  str: "Algum texto",
  id: 5
};
console.log(algumObjeto);
```

```html
Observar a saída no console do navegador!
```

Você também pode utilizar substituição de string e outros argumentos com este método. Por exemplo:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  console.log("Olá, %s. Você me chamou pela %dª vez.", "João", i+1);
}
```

Saída:

```
Olá, João. Você me chamou pela 1ª vez.
Olá, João. Você me chamou pela 2ª vez.
Olá, João. Você me chamou pela 3ª vez.
Olá, João. Você me chamou pela 4ª vez.
Olá, João. Você me chamou pela 5ª vez.
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Olá, %s. Você me chamou pela %dª vez.", "João", i + 1);
}
```

```html
<p>Observar a saída no console do navegador!</p>
```

**Limitações e falte de suporte**

Esse recurso pode não estar disponível ou ativo no browser, então sempre deve-se testar sua existência antes de tentar utiliza-lo:

```
// verifica se o objeto window.console existe
if (window.console){
    window.console.log("Log isto");
}
```

**Observações importantes**

Além das situações citadas anteriormente, versões antiga do IE, ou `< IE9`, não apresentam este método da forma apresentada anteriormente (com o mesmo nome/assinatura) ou não apresentam, como citado nessas referencias:

- [What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)
- [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)
- [Using the F12 Tools Console to View Errors and Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Complete cross-browser console.log()](http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/); (Este ultimo demonstrando como tratar esse recurso em todos os browsers)

<sup>Fonte: [MDN Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

uma maneira de depurar seu codigo. Esse comando irá mostrar no console de seu navegador o que estiver escrito na função log.