# Como mostrar os valores armazenados no JSON em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Tem uma variável em um arquivo `JSON` que se chama "valore" e ela está atribuindo os valores:2.51,2.56,2.87,2.89 e 2.94. 
A string desse JSON está sendo exibida em uma `DIV`. Como faço para mostrar somente esses valores?

Comment: Mostrar os valores dentro da div? Você pode atribuir um `ID` a div e fazer algo como: `document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = valore;`

Comment: @PedroHenrique Os numeros dos quais escritos a cima formaram um gráfico.Já tentei utilizar esse comando mais infelizmente não funcionol...

Comment: Você utiliza alguma biblioteca para formar este gráfico? Pode explicar melhor onde você deseja mostrar os valores e como você deseja mostrar os valores?

Comment: Pode mostrar exatamente como estão os dados? Coloque `console.log(valore)` e pegue o resultado do [console do seu browser](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log/38085#38085).

Comment: Sim utilizo a RGraph para copm ela fazer o gráfico, quero mostrar aqueles valores em uma variavel na página html... pois o gráfico já está pronto e tenho que pegar esse valores do servido automatico.

Comment: O que você quer é pegar os valores de um JSON, e não a variavel JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito explicativa, mas vou tentar te ajudar com o que entendi...

Bom primeiro você tem que "pegar" este JSON, assim que você pega-lo você tera 1 objeto JSON na sua mão.
Para tratar este objeto você precisa passar por cada um dos seus atributos e exibir somente aqueles que lhe interessam, vou te mostrar um código que fiz estes dias para um objetivo semelhante.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "ENDEREÇO DO SEU JSON",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, desafio) {
            item = "<center><h4>" + desafio.meta + "</h4></center>";

            if (desafio.id == $('#selectDesafio').val() ) {
                $('#blocodesafio').html(''),
                $('#blocodesafio').append(item);
            }
        });
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Erro ao carregar');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Neste código eu selecionei cada Meta do meu desafio e atribui de acordo com o valor do meu selectDesafio.
Espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito de como esses dados estão arquivados nesse JSON. Por exemplo, pode ser que existem assim:

```
{ valore: [ 2.51, 2.56, 2.87, 2.89, 2.94 ] }
```

Se for, pondo esse valor num `<div>` talvez não mostre exatamente o que você quer. Nesse caso, usando jQuery, pode fazer um `$.each()`, assim:

```
var html = "";
$.each(valore, function(i) {
   html = i + ', ' + html;
});
$('#idDoDiv').html(html);
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar um valor do seu objeto JSON:

```
var dados = { valore: [ 2.51, 2.56, 2.87, 2.89, 2.94 ] };

//aqui vc está pegando o primeiro valor
dados.valore[0];
//também pode ser acessado assim:
dados['valore'][0];
```

Para pegar a cadeia inteira, você pode simplesmente concatenar tudo usando join com seu concatenador, já que se trata de um array:

```
dados.valore.join(",");
```

Ou fazer um simples for:

```
for (var i in dados.valore) {
     console.log(dados.valore[i]); //envia pro console o valor
}
```

Para tratar uma saida POST do objeto:

Antes de enviar para uma variável, você precisa fazer um parseJSON, no javascript puro seria `JSON.parse(data)`, porém o jQuery tem um método que faz uma tratativa mais elaborada:

```
$.post('/url_enviada', function(data) {
         //retorno dos dados-> data
          var dados = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(dados.valore.join("\n"));
});
```

Existem outras formas não muito recomendadas de você fazer parse no objeto JSON:

```
var dados = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

ou

```
var dados;
eval('dados = ' + data);
```

E caso o seu método seja um ajax, já informando o tipo de dado esperado, não é necessário fazer o parse, ele internamente já está te retornando objeto, quando você informa o tipo de **dataType**:

```
  $.ajax({ 
         type: 'POST', //método POST, GET, PUT...
         url: "url_enviada", //url que irá construir o json_encode()
         dataType: 'json', //aqui ele define o tipo de dado esperado
         contentType: 'application/json', //para converter a saída em utf-8
         crossDomain: true, //para não ter bloqueio de crossDomain
         cache:false //para não fazer cache
         }) //promises
        .done(function(data) {
         $( "#element_div" ).html( data.valore[0] +'<br>' + data.valore[1] );
         })
        .fail(function() {
         $( "#element_div" ).html( "erro no processo!" );
         }) 
        .always(function() {
         })
        .then(function() {
         });
```

Comment: acredito que já é bastante seguro usar o `JSON.parse`, afinal até o IE8 suporta ele (fonte: [ca i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json)). o `jQuery.parseJSON` basicamente verifica se o `JSON.parse` está disponível, se não estiver usa um `eval()`. No mais sempre tenho vontade de colocar a seguinte conteúdo nas paginas que escrevo: `<!--[if lte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://outdatedbrowser.com/pt" /><![endif]-->`