# Como pegar um .JSON de uma URL com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Olhei alguns exemplos da documentação do jQuery, porem ainda não consegui.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var endereco = 'http://10.20.229.17:8085/todosPostos';

        $.ajax({
            url: endereco,
            complete: function(res){
                var data = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                console.log(data); 
            }
        });  
    </script>
</head>
<form action="testeste.html" method="post">
    <select>
        <option value="trechoorigem">Trecho (Origem)</option>
        <option value="trechodestino">Trecho (Destino)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
</body>



</html>
```

Console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.20.229.17:8085/todosPostos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Comment: Você está realizando uma chamada cross domain, ou seja, tentando consumir a API (http://10.20.229.17:8085/) de outro servidor (ou domínio). Você precisa habilitar sua API para permitir requisições Cross-domain.

Comment: Essa resposta aqui mesmo no SO explica um pouco sobre CORS: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis#answer-3251

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior Não sei se isso influencia em algo, mas essa API está em uma VPN que eu estou conectado. Outro problema, é que eu não estou conseguindo pegar o JSON nem localmente.

Comment: Se por exemplo, você está realizando a chamada na sua página (localhost:8080) e tua api está em outro endereço (ex localhost:9999) você já está realizando uma chamada cross domain. Recomendo alterar a API para aceitar esse tipo de requisição. A forma de configuração vai depender da linguagem de rpogramação que está utilizando na API.

Comment: dentro do ajax, coloque: `crossDomain: true,`, conforme esse exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54524/como-mostrar-os-valores-armazenados-no-json-em-javascript/95061#95061 e no PHP: antes do json_encode(), coloque isso: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: @IvanFerrer `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'http://10.90.226.87:8085/todosPostos',
            complete: function(res){
                var data = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                console.log(data); 
            }
        });  ` o data retorna: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.90.226.87:8085/todosPostos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Não sei se existe esse "complete", acho é "success". e outra, em ajax, não precisa fazer parse, leia na resposta do link que te passei.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você precisa configurar sua API para aceitar requisições Cross Domain

Esse artigo explica como fazer isso se você utiliza php: http://www.loiane.com/2014/01/requests-ajax-com-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-entre-sencha-touch-e-extjs-e-backend/

E se usa C#: http://www.brenoqueiroz.com.br/habilitando-cors-asp-net-webapi/

Se você usa Java ou Python tem um link dentro do primeiro post.

Comment: Seria interessante se postasse um trecho do artigo referente a isso para caso se algum dia o site sair do ar ou mudarem o endereço não dar problemas de visualização :)

Comment: Entendi, mas vou explicar a minha situação para ver se você consegue me dar uma help. Estou usando essa API para desenvolver um Dashboard em HTML+JS, vou montar umas tabelas e uns gráficos com os dados extraídos. Porém esse dashboard vai rodar no mesmo servidor da API. Queria usar somente JS para pegar esses dados e popular meus gráficos/tabelas, porém não estou conseguindo nem mesmo pegar os dados de um arquivo .JSON local.

Comment: Fazendo o que eu falei você vai conseguir resolver o problema do exemplo que você postou, quanto ao caso do JSON local você deveria postar mais detalhes pois está muito vago. Não tenho como saber o erro que ocorre, como você está fazendo essa chamada, pode ser muitas coisas. Eu acho que isso é conteúdo para outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o método nativo:

**Para passar:**

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);
var url + '?' + json_text;
```

**Para recuperar:**

```
var json = JSON.parse(url.split('?')[1]);
```

Comment: Emir, não entendi direito. Consegues aplicar esse método no código exemplo que eu postei na pergunta?

Comment: Não entendi teu código. Você está tentando converter o retorno da tua consulta certo? De um console.log no res. Ao que parece não está sendo retornado um json válido.

Comment: Sim, eu até o momento estava desenvolvendo com o json direto em uma variável, porem agora preciso pegar de uma URL. Não tem como você ver ai, pois essa API está em uma VPN onde tenho acesso.

Comment: Post através do console.log o conteúdo da variável res

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UkPxorW.jpg Aqui está o console.log do res

Comment: Pelo visto o teu problema não está na chamada. Vc está passando os dados de forma correta? O server espera um post ou get etc?

Comment: Não sei te responder isso Emir, sobre o servidor eu não sei o que se passa por lá.

Comment: O servidor é de um terceiro?