# Duvida com javascript console.log

Tags: javascript, console

eu tenho um javascript que executa algumas ações em um site. Eu acompanho pelo console pra saber o que ta acontecendo, porem em varios momentos ele executa um comando que printa no console console.log("check");

Eu quero fazer com que esse "check" nao apareça no console, porque ele se repete o tempo todo e suja a tela. se eu simplesmente apagar console.log("check") ele para de funcionar? ou apenas para de printar no console?

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas para de printar no console. A função `console.log` serve apenas para printar algo no console, não faz nada além disso.

Você encontra mais informações sobre o console aqui no site mesmo: [O que é console.log?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057)