# Buscar dados PHP pelo Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

estou com um script Ajax aqui que a função dele é a seguinte.. Tenho um sistema de notícias, que ao clicar no titulo vai abrir uma modal e me exibir os dados da noticia (titulo, texto, autor).. porem não sei o que colocar no PHP..

Este é o código js

```
var News = {
Init: function(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'noticia.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'id': id},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('body').animate({'opacity':'0.5'});
        },success: function(data) {
            $('body').animate({'opacity':'1'});
            var Html = '';
                Html+='<div id="modal" class="animated bounceInDown">';
                Html+='     <div class="ler_content animated bounceInDown"> <div id="close_new" onclick="Alerta.Close()"></div>';
                Html+='         <div class="titulo">';
                Html+='            <div class="img" style="background: url('+data['imagem']+');">';
                Html+='            </div>';
                Html+='           <div class="autor">'+data['autor']+'</div>';
                Html+='           <span>'+data['titulo']+'</span>';
                Html+='        </div>';
                Html+='        <div class="texto">'+data['texto']+'</div>';
                Html+='     </div>';
                Html+=' </div>';

            $('body').prepend(Html);

        }

    })



}}
```

o que estou tentando colocar no noticia.php é isso, mas sei qeu esta errado..

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['id'] );
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT id, titulo, imagem, autor, texto
    FROM noticias
    WHERE id=$id
    ORDER BY id";
$res = mysql_query( $sql );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
$data[] = array(
    'id'    => $row['id'],
    'titulo'            => $row['titulo'],
    'imagem'            => $row['imagem'],
    'autor'         => $row['autor'],
    'texto'         => $row['texto'],
);}
echo( json_encode( $data ) );
```

Me ajudem!!

Comment: Onde está o problema? Algum erro ou algo que não funciona?

Comment: quando abro a notícia ela não exibe o que deveria

Comment: Algum erro? mostra alguma coisa? o que dá `console.log(data);` dentro desse `success` do Ajax?

Comment: beforeSend: function(){
            $('body').animate({'opacity':'0.5'});
        },success: function(data) {
            $('body').animate({'opacity':'1'});

Se ele não retorna o "sucess" a pagina fica 0.5 de transparencia..

Comment: Sabes o que é `console.log`? já testaste isso que pedi?

Comment: não entendo muito disso, no mesmo ja em outra função tem um "console.log('Init');"

Comment: Lê isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/129 e depois responde à pergunta aqui nos comentários.

Comment: cara, não entendi muito bem, mas me resume, o que quer que eu faça?

Comment: A melhor maneira de te ajudar é fazer-te ler aquela pergunta e respostas. Já perguntei o que preciso saber para te ajudar. Fico à espera da resposta se quiseres mais ajuda. Acredita que vale a pena ler :)

Comment: Sergio, eu não entendo dessa linguagem, li o que me falou e fiquei perdido no assunto..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSPMRDcq9Co

Comment: ok, acho que entendi agora, acrescentei ao final da função News console.log('News'); e verifiquei que o sucess modificou meu body acrescentando um style="opacity: 0.5;", porem nao mostrou o restante que deveria

Comment: Ele executa o "beforeSend: function(){
                $('body').animate({'opacity':'0.5'});
            }" porem não exibe o sucess depois

Comment: Sergio, agora sim está funcionando, mas um detalhe, os valores estão retornando como "Undefinied"