# Utilidades de console.log()

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo uma refatoração num código feito no formato **MVC**, deixando o código mais legível, eliminando código duplicado e deletando variáveis e *API's* que não estavam mais sendo usadas.

Ao deletar alguns "`console.log(algo.aqui)`", fui questionado do porque elimina-los, prontamente respondi que era algo que um dos milhares de programadores que já mexeram ali tinha esquecido após verificar e validar algum valor no console.

Ele me informou que `console.log()` não é algo usado somente para validar o valor de uma variável, que também tem suas aplicações tanto no front-end quanto no back-end da aplicação.

Ao pesquisar não achei muita coisa.

Então gostaria de saber:

- Quais são as utilidades de `console.log()` no *front-end*
- Quais são as utilidades de `console.log()` no *back-end*?
- Quais os efeitos que levam ao seu uso? O que ele difere de simplesmente passar a variável?

Comment: Esquisito negativarem sem comentarios, ainda mais que não infringi nenhuma regra de pergunta. Genuinamente quero saber, mesmo se for uma resposta como: não, não existe outra função pra isso.

Comment: Também não entendi pq negativaram, talvez nem a pessoa que negativou entenda o pq. kkk

Comment: @abfurlan retiraram o negativo

Comment: Não seria duplicada:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log . E não foi eu quem negativou =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`console.log` vai chamar o método `log` do objeto console.

> Parabéns Capitão Óbvio, essa informação mudou a minha vida!

Calma, jovem. Ocorre que a implementação do objeto console é diferente em cada ambiente.

É tranquilo afirmar que, no caso mais normal, o console envolvido é o do navegador. Mas a depender do seu ambiente, esse objeto pode escrever dados em locais diferentes. Sua aplicação pode ser executada em um ambiente de desenvolvimento ou de testes, ao invés do navegador. Nesses casos, o console no qual os dados serão escritos será o dessa ferramenta.

Já para o backend: o console pode ser uma janela externa. Enquanto a aplicação é executada, o administrador pode ter uma ideia do que acontece por baixo dos panos. Isso é útil para quem trabalha com Javascript no servidor (vide node.js).

Comment: Estava esperando alguém citar o nodejs rs +1

Answer (score 4):

Como o pessoal falou acima usado basicamente como um debugger do seu código, mas vou dar um exemplo onde o **console.log()** ajuda muito, atualmente trabalho com frameworks como Angular e Vue.js, com esses frameworks criamos varias camadas em nosso frontend (Controller, Service, Factory, etc) com o console.log() podemos analisar o estado dos dados que estão sendo trafegados entre as camadas, isso é importante porque conseguimos ver onde e quando os dados estão sendo processados e alterados.

Vale lembrar que o objeto console possui também outros métodos, tais como:

- console.error()
- console.info()
- console.debug()
- console.profile()

Answer (score 3):

É um recurso JavaScript usado para depuração (debugar).

Ele gera logs que podem ser consultados no console do browser.

No Google Chrome, pressione CTRL + SHIFT + I, escolha "console". É nesse local onde os logs serão impressos.

Cada browser possui um console específico. Vale salientar que browsers em versões mais antigas não suportam esse recurso.

Utilidade no backend? Que eu saiba é nulo pois é um recurso do frontend entre JavaScript e o Browser.

> Quais os efeitos que levam ao seu uso? O que ele difere de
>   simplesmente passar a variável?

Não tem o que comparar com "passagem de variáveis" pois são coisas muito distintas. É meramente um recurso de auxílio para depuração de scripts. Antigamente tínhamos que usar o `alert()` o qual se tornava um problema num loop infinito solto por engano, por exemplo, pois o browser mantinha os `alert()` infinitamente. Além do mais é silencioso e pode inclusive deixá-lo ativo em ambiente de produção, desde que não comprometa a segurança.

A utilidade em deixar ativo é que facilita até no suporte a um cliente. Um cliente que reclama que não consegue navegar numa página, você pode pedir para o cliente fazer um printscreen do log do console. Isso ajuda muito principalmente quando o cliente é leigo e não sabe dizer direito o que se passa.

Um cuidado que deve ter é que os browsers possuem recursos para manter um histórico dos logs. Se salvou logs de dados sensíveis é um risco sério para segurança pois uma pessoa má intencionada com acesso ao computador da vítima pode ver facilmente os logs do console.

Answer (score 1):

Uso bastante JavaScript, hoje o console.log pra mim tem a função de validar se algumas rotinas estão funcionando como deveriam.
Exemplo tenho uma aplicação de faz vários cálculos para vende de produtos
e sempre que um calculo é feito ele da um log com console.log uma informação contendo como o calculo foi feito.
E essa informação é enviada para um arquivo para analises futuras.

Não sei se seria uma usabilidade do console.log, mais fica diga.

Answer (score 0):

O Console.log é utilizando apenas para debugar informações nos brownsers (Firefox com Firebug, Chrome, IE8).