# Comparar dois valores com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como que eu faço para comparar duas variáveis. Tenho uma variável que traz o id do bairro, chamada bairrocadastrado, ela retorna o ID do bairro igual 1093. Logo eu tenho um foreach que retorna todos os bairros cadastrados no sistema, tipo bairro_id 995, 1093 etc. Só que o problema é o seguinte. Ele encontra o ID. Faz a comparação, mas sempre retorna os bairros que não são iguais, ou seja o segundo IF, sendo que são iguais. O que pode estar errado?

```
  function areasAtendimento()
  {
    // inicia as variaveis
    var id_atendimento = "";
    var id_bairro = "";
    var nomebairro = "";
    var nomecidade = "";
    var nomeestado = "";
    var valorfrete = "";
    var parseResult = "";
    var cidadecadastrada = "";
    var bairrocadastrado = "";
    var resultBairro = "";

    // pegar os itens do session storage
    var getEnderecoLogado = sessionStorage.getItem("dadosendereco");

    $.ajax({
      url: urlBase + "areaatendimento",
      method: 'GET',
      success: function (retorno)
      {

        parseResult = JSON.parse(getEnderecoLogado);
        bairrocadastrado = parseResult[parseResult.length-1].bairroendereco;

        retorno.data.forEach(function (item)
        {
          id_atendimento = item.area_atendimento_id;
          id_bairro = item.bairro.bairro_id;
          nomecidade = item.bairro.municipio.nome;
          nomebairro = item.bairro.nome;
          nomeestado = item.bairro.municipio.estado.nome;
          valorfrete = item.valor_frete;
          valorfrete = valorfrete.replace('.', ',');
          // bairro igual ao que está cadastrado
          if (id_bairro == bairrocadastrado)
          {
            $('.entregatotal').html("R$" + valorfrete);
            $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'block');
          }
          // bairro diferete, não exibe o botão
          if (id_bairro != bairrocadastrado)
          {
            $('.entregatotal').html("R$ 0,00");
            $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'none');
            $('.nao-atendido').css('display','block');
          }
        })
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        console.log('Erro');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Os operadores no javascript precisam ser mais especificos para os ifs, use exatamente igual '===' e '!=='

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof id_bairro, id_bairro, typeof bairrocadastrado, bairrocadastrado);`?

Comment: Felipe, viste a minha pergunta ^ ? se não sabes [usar a consola](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/129) faz com alert 1 a 1 e responde aqui o que te dá.

Comment: Sim, o problema é que ele retorna todos os ids dos bairros cadastrados e na hora de comparar faz os dois ifs. Compara o que existe e depois os que não existem dizendo que é diferente. Mais detalhes no rodapé aqui da discussão.

Comment: Qual das variáveis é uma array?

Comment: bairrocadastrado é um array do sessionstorage que pega o id do bairro cadastrado pelo cliente que é 10813. Logo id_bairro são todos os bairros cadastrados que vem dentro do ajax, ou seja dentro do foreach. Nessa variável também vem o id do bairro 10813

Comment: E queres saber se`id_bairro` existe em `bairrocadastrado`, certo? Qual é a estrutura de `bairrocadastrado`? É uma array de strings/numeros?

Comment: bairro cadastrado vem deste sessionStorage sendo como numero: Pega o último do array [{"idcliente":"ecca2c6b-cd15-443b-b4db-5a15d39196c5","cliente_endereco_id":"69b8626d-c8d0-44a0-933a-e38e1a2737cd","cependereco":"89400000","logradouroendereco":"Rua Jaime Correia Pereira","numeroendereco":"90","complementoendereco":"Casa","referencia":"Centro Comunitário","estadoendereco":"Santa Catarina","cidadeendereco":"Porto União","bairroendereco":10813}]

Comment: Ok, e nessa array o valor que queres comparar é o de `bairroendereco`? ou seja verificar se `id_bairro` é igual a `"bairroendereco":10813`?

Comment: sim isso mesmo. Só que fiquei nessa do loop e ele não sai disso. Ele pega todos os que são e os que não e compara.kkkkk

Comment: Felipe, usa `@` antes do nome para eu receber uma notificação, senão passam horas antes que veja o teu comentário :) Ok, então uma ultima pergunta: essa array `bairrocadastrado` pode ter mais que um objeto dentro? ou vem sempre com 1 só objeto dentro da array?

Comment: @Sergio, somente 1 objeto o id do bairro

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca ok, seria caso então de teres `bairrocadastrado = parseResult[parseResult.length-1].bairroendereco[0].bairroendereco`? Fica bem longo mas parece-me a mudança minima a fazer  no código.

Comment: sim @Sergio, mas isso resolveria o problema do IF?

Comment: Sim, o if está certo. O problema é a variável `bairrocadastrado` não ter o que esperavas. Se `bairrocadastrado` estiver certo o `if` vai funcionar. Podias ter `if (id_bairro == bairrocadastrado)` e em baixo `else` em vêz de `if (id_bairro != bairrocadastrado)`. Era um bocadinho melhor para a leitura do código, mas não está errado e o problema não são os `!=` `==` neste caso.

Comment: desculpe @Sergio, mas volta o seguinte erro: Cannot read property 'bairroendereco' of undefined

Comment: Ok, voltando um passo atrás. Coloca aqui o valor de `console.log(typeof getEnderecoLogado, getEnderecoLogado);` sem `JSON.parse`, logo a seguir a `var getEnderecoLogado =`.

Comment: na verdade @Sergio o if funciona só que eu queria que ele mostre se o frete do bairroendereco é igual ao id do foreach. Mas dai ele retorna todos os que são diferentes também, porque ele é diferente entendeu? Acredito que o erro esteja aí, só não sabemos como fazer para que ele retorne os valores corretos e para que ele pare no primeiro if se for igual e não execute o segundo.

Comment: @Sergio ele volta: string [{"idcliente":"ecca2c6b-cd15-443b-b4db-5a15d39196c5","cliente_endereco_id":"69b8626d-c8d0-44a0-933a-e38e1a2737cd","cependereco":"89400000","logradouroendereco":"Rua Jaime Correia Pereira","numeroendereco":"90","complementoendereco":"Casa","referencia":"Centro Comunitário","estadoendereco":"Santa Catarina","cidadeendereco":"Porto União","bairroendereco":10813}]

Comment: Em relação ao que vem do `getEnderecoLogado` a maneira correta é `bairrocadastrado = parseResult[0].bairroendereco;`, uma vez que é só 1. Em relação a _"ele retorna todos os que são diferentes também"_ e _"não sabemos como fazer para que ele retorne os valores corretos"_ ainda não percebi a que te referes. Referest-e ao `retorno` do ajax ou ao sessionStorage?

Answer (score 1):

O segundo IF está substituindo o primeiro.
Tenta alterar para um ELSE ou ELSE IF, assim:

```
// bairro igual ao que está cadastrado
      if (id_bairro == bairrocadastrado)
      {
        $('.entregatotal').html("R$" + valorfrete);
        $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'block');
      } 
      else if (id_bairro != bairrocadastrado)
      {
        $('.entregatotal').html("R$ 0,00");
        $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'none');
        $('.nao-atendido').css('display','block');
      }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: _"O segundo IF está substituindo o primeiro"_ ? Como assim? podes dar um exemplo como isso pode acontecer?

Comment: O que ele disse faz sentido, pois primeiro, ele ve 'se bairro igual' e depois ele manda executar 'se bairro diferente' dentro do mesmo loop, o segundo if vai ser o que vai ser executado por ultimo, pode ser isso mesmo que preencha errado.

Comment: Ele faz sempre o segundo IF. Ou seja, ele acha todos e se for diferente como ele encontra todos que são, ele já faz o segundo. O caso é que está encontrando todos os iguais e todos os diferentes. Mas eu queria somente os iguais.

Comment: Você tem a mesma classe para os dois IFs, então se ele entrar no primeiro e depois no segundo.. O segundo vai prevalecer, você colocando o ELSE ou ELSE IF, ele vai entrar em um ou em outro...

Comment: Como que faria para resolver isso então? Tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca , você não tem nada mandando o loop parar a hora que encontrar os igual, ou usa um else indicando exceção, ou manda o loop parar a hora que encontrar o igual. um return 0 ja é o suficiente

Comment: Não entendi. Poderia me explicar? Sou iniciante em Javascript e jquery

Comment: Tentei com return false e não deu em nada, nesta situação. Não seria melhor fazer um contador?

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca coloca o nome das classes diferentes, como se fosse criar duas div mesmo, talvez já resolva... Tipo  $('.entregatotal').html("R$" + valorfrete); e no ELSE  $('.entregatotalNaoCad').html("R$" + valorfrete);... Mas altere dos outros campos tbm.. E depois vc trata com show(mostrar) ou hidden(esconder) ql vc quer exibir... Acho que ficaria mais fácil

Comment: Não há números válidos em formato _String_ ou _Number_ que dêem o mesmo resultado em `!=` e `==`. Daí o meu `-1`.

Answer (score -1):

Tente modificar essa parte:

```
if (id_bairro === bairrocadastrado)
{
    $('.entregatotal').html("R$" + valorfrete);
    $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'block');
    return false;
} else
{
    $('.entregatotal').html("R$ 0,00");
    $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'none');
    $('.nao-atendido').css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: Já tentei tudo o que falaram  e não deu em nada.kkkk. Coisa tão fácil dando dor de cabeça

Comment: Da um var_dump em 'retorno' antes de vir pro JS, upa no pastebin e manda o link, ta estranho isso kk

Comment: Tá na resposta do de cima...kkkk