# Retornar dados do banco na <label> com Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, assincronismo

Preciso retornar os dados do banco dentro dos inputs quando selecionado o botão "Editar" sem que a pagina seja recarregada, contudo, ao clicar em "Editar", vejo que a ação do botão muda, conforme o código javascript, porém os inputs não são preenchidos com os dados que se encontram no banco. Segue o script:

```
$(document).on('click','.update', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"../control/control_salvaEdicao.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        datatype:"json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#action').text("Editar");
            $('#id').val(id);
            $('#nome').val(data.nome);
            $('#sobrenome').val(data.sobrenome);
            $('#endereco').val(data.endereco);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Cadastro de Pessoas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Style.css"/>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="Js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tudo">
        <div id="pessoas">      
        </div>
        <div id="boxcentral" align="center">
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"/>
            </br></br>
            <label>Sobrenome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome"/>
            </br></br>
            <label>Endereço: </label>
            <input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco"/>
            </br></br>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>
            <button type="button" name="action" id="action">adicionar</button>
            <div id="resultado">
            </div>  
        </div>
```

> Arquivo **editaEvento.php**

```
if (isset ($_POST['id'])){

$pessoa = new Pessoa();
$peopleDAO = new PessoaDAO();   

$pessoa->getId($_POST['id']);

        $retornoPessoa = $peopleDAO->buscaPessoaID($pessoa);

        if($retornoPessoa != null){
            foreach ($retornoPessoa as $obj){
                $obj->getId();  
                $obj->getNome();    
                $obj->getSobrenome();   
                $obj->getEndereco();
            }

            return $obj;

        }
}
```

> Arquivo **salvaEdicao.php**

```
if($_POST["action"]== "editar"){    
$pessoa = new Pessoa();
$pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();   

    $pessoa->setId($_POST['id']);
    $pessoa->setNome($_POST['nome']);
    $pessoa->setSobrenome($_POST['sobrenome']);
    $pessoa->setEndereco($_POST['endereco']);



    try{
        $resultado = $pessoaDAO->update($pessoa);
    }catch(exeption $e){
        $erro=$e->getmessage();
        echo $erro;
    }

    if ($resultado == true){
        $sucess_message="Cadastro atualizado com sucesso!";
        echo $sucess_message;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o html?

Comment: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Não seria o caso de imprimir o retorno no **Console**? `console.log(data);` para ver se está tendo retorno e como ele esta vindo ?

Comment: Posta o retono do backend e do script control_salvaEdicao.php

Comment: Também achei estranho o return, está usando algum "framework"?
é melhor mudar o header pra responder como json também (n sei se fez em outro lugar)

Comment: e se remover o foreach e fizer return $retornoPessoa[0]?

Comment: eu tentaria antes de tudo echo json_encode($retornoPessoa); die(); só pra ver

Comment: @wmsouza, efetuei a alteração e ficou assim https://repl.it/@lucaalmec/IntentAgonizingQueenslandheeler, porém o problema ainda persiste

Comment: Apenas verifico no HTML se as inputs são preenchidas. Como faço para imprimir no console?

Comment: Dentro de `success:function(data)` no **JavaScript** coloque a linha `console.log(data);`, veja: [O que é console.log?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/) e estiver utilizando o **Chrome** o atalho para abrir é `CTRL+SHIT+I`

Comment: com o Console.log não me retorna informação alguma na tela, porém testei com o Alert usando alert(data.nome)... e todos estão como indefinidos com exceção do ID que já é atribuído pelo botão "Editar"

Comment: Certo, agora veja que você só esta enviando o `id` como parâmetro, tem que enviar os campos também, veja [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/RundownKeenTapaculo)

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa, todos os campos continuam indefinidos com exceção do ID...

Answer (score 0):

você só está retornando uma mensagem de sucesso, o que você tem que fazer é retornar o objeto atualizado:

php:

```
 if ($resultado == true){
            $sucess_message="Cadastro atualizado com sucesso!";
            echo json_encode([
                   'message' => $sucess_message, 
                   'pessoa' => $pessoa
            ]);
    }
```

ajax:

```
$(document).on('click','.update', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"../control/control_salvaEdicao.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        datatype:"json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#action').text("Editar");
            $('#id').val(data.pessoa.id);
            $('#nome').val(data.pessoa.nome);
            $('#sobrenome').val(data.pessoa.sobrenome);
            $('#endereco').val(data.pessoa.endereco);
        }
    });
});
```

Isso quando você clicar no evento para salvar né, caso seja no evento para puxar os dados acredito que só a URL do seu `ajax` que está incorreta, deveria ser `url:"../control/control_editaEvento.php"`

Experimente colocar também um `console.log` no seu retorno do Ajax para ver como está vindo o resultado, pois se vier do arquivo editaEvento.php a maneira correta de pegar os dados é:

```
$('#action').text("Editar");
$('#id').val(data.id);
$('#nome').val(data.nome);
$('#sobrenome').val(data.sobrenome);
$('#endereco').val(data.endereco);
```

O `ID` provavelmente está vindo preenchido porque note você pega o valor da variável que você passa para o ajax.