# Transformar esse código jQuery em Javascript puro

Tags: javascript

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var posicao = $(window).scrollTop();
    var cor = Math.round(posicao / 1000);
    $('.social li a').css('border-color', pegarCor(cor));
   });
   pegarCor = function(cor){
     switch(cor){
       case 1:
         return "#ff0ff0";
         break;
       case 2:
         return "#00aabc";
         break;
       case 3:
         return "#00ee54";
         break;
       case 4:
         return "#334454";
         break;
       case 5:
         return "#ff00ff";
         break;
       default:
         return "#00aa12";
         break;
     }
   }
```

```js
<!-- codigo jquery -->

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var posicao = $(window).scrollTop();
    var cor = Math.round(posicao / 1000);
    $('.social li a').css('border-color', pegarCor(cor));
   });
   pegarCor = function(cor){
     switch(cor){
       case 1:
         return "#ff0ff0";
         break;
       case 2:
         return "#00aabc";
         break;
       case 3:
         return "#00ee54";
         break;
       case 4:
         return "#334454";
         break;
       case 5:
         return "#ff00ff";
         break;
       default:
         return "#00aa12";
         break;
     }
   }


<!-- codigo javascript -->
window.onscroll = function(){
    var position = window.scrollTop;
    var color = Math.round(position / 1000);

    document.querySelectorAll(".social li a").style.borderColor = selectColor(color);
}

selectColor = function(color){
    switch(color){
        case 1:
          cor = "#ff0ff0";
          break;
        case 2:
            cor = "#00aabc";
          break;
        case 3:
            cor = "#00ee54";
          break;
        case 4:
            cor = "#334454";
          break;
        case 5:
          cor = "#ff00ff";
          break;
        default:
          cor = "#00aa12";
          break;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Seu erro é que não existe um equivalente direto do `.css(...)` em javascript puro. Você precisa de algum tipo de loop em cima do retorno do `document.querySelectorAll(".social li a")`. Não dá pra alterar o `style` de todo mundo direto dali. Atribua a lista de elementos a uma variável, faça o loop e atribua os estilos (ou, melhor ainda, uma classe) a cada um:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".social li a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.add('classe');

    // ou:
    // links[i].style.borderColor = selectColor(color);
}
```

## Como eu ia saber disso?

Parece que faltou você verificar o console do seu navegador, que deve ter emitido centenas de mensagens de erro durante o rolamento. Ou pelo menos faltou você contar isso na pergunta (o que explica em parte os negativos que recebeu).

Sempre teste seu código com o console aberto (se não sabe como, veja [O que é console.log?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log)). Ele vai dar uma mensagem de erro útil, dizendo em que linha do seu código está o problema, e qual erro deu. Neste caso, o seu console deve ter informado algo como *Não é possível acessar a propriedade borderColor de undefined*. Isso porque a lista de elementos não tem propriedade `style`.

Comment: +1, o "Como eu ia saber disso" é o que tem faltado em muitas respostas do site. Dá um peixe pronto, mas já ensina a pescar o próximo.